# Android linker failing to resolve static function symbols when linking to other shared libraries

Tags: android, c++

This is regarding the linker issue during soong build in Android.

I want to create four shared objects sample1.so, sample2.so, sample3.so and sample4.so which has native c++ code.

sample1 library has a micro defined to a static function call. Static function is defined under three different namespaces with different number of arguments but with same name. And the static function is used for other libraries by using the macro for logging functionality. Other libraries use the macro by including the header file where macro is defined and  linking sample1 in the corresponding Android.bp file shared_libs. Sample1.so is created first and is linked to other three .so files as a dependency.

Linking of the static function to other three libraries is failing with error "undefined symbol on the static function.

In the objdump of sample1.so i can see the symbol under three different name spaces with different signatures.

In the .o files of sample2, sample3 and sample4 the static symbol is undefined. As per my understanding in .o files symbol will be undefined and during linking it will get resolved, but is not happening so.

Can someone help me in fixing the linker issue. Thank you.

I tried by setting different properties like visibility, export_shared_lib_headers.

It works with allow_undefined_symbols but it should not be used as the modules should not contain undefined symbols.

Comment: Do you mean "1. a C static function" or "2. a CPP static function of a class"?

Comment: Hello zomega, i mean here it's CPP static function.

Comment: Is it inside a class? Is it public, protected or private?

Comment: Yes it is inside a class overloaded under three different namespaces.

Comment: You need a header file with the class definition and its static function (without implementation). This file needs to be included in sample2.so, sample3.so and sample4.so. Please show me this header file (only the necessary part).

Comment: It's done in the same way,  inside a class under public access specifier the static function declaration is present under some xyz namespace. And this header file is included in sample2, sample3 and sample4. Sorry for unable to share the actual code here.